# Is there a library that finds contents from a bunch of files in a directory and does indexing of it in nodejs

Tags: node.js, indexing, lucene

Is there a library that finds contents from a bunch of files (any files ) in a directory and does reverse-indexing of it based on files names (like lucene ) i din't find any library  that does something  like this.

I feel i will have two look this two things separately ? (no idea )

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-client . Solr is based on Lucene.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-node (older, but still another one)